# .Net Core 3.1 MVC with Identity feature, while running via IIS producing 404 error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, identity

Just to make it convenient, here is the link to the most updated code
(1) https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development
(2) Git branch: Stackoverflow_Yinqiu
(3) https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development.git

Can someone please explore and help find the gap. Please feel free to push to another branch into the same repository mmm_development.

Thanks a lot i advance for the cooperation.

Comment: The Registration failed to navigate to the Login page. The 404 issue might  have been fixed by adding the AddDefaultUI() into AddIdentity<>.. as follows

Comment: services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config =>
            {
                //config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<MedicalManagerDBContext>().AddDefaultUI().AddDefaultTokenProviders(); in the Startup.cs ConfiguarationService()

Comment: However, currently, managed to show Login & Registration but the Registration does not navigate into the page neither it does conduct the Registration as user fails to Login

Comment: Hi @Bite-us,any update about this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [project](https://github.com/biteus/mmm_development/tree/Yinqiu),and change startup.

Your startup should be flowing:

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You  are Great!!!!!!.. It did work. However, I wonder, I had those already added in the application but was not as you showed sequence. Anyway, it works and from now on, I will make sure to map them as you showed here. Thanks a lot..